# Confused on how token system works with Auth0 and Azure AD

Tags: azure-active-directory, auth0

I have configured my SPA application in Auth0 and works fine. Now I have tried to connect my azure AD to Auth0 with PKCE flow, so user logs in with outlook account. This also works fine.

I am having few questions on azure AD with Auth0

1) Where do we get authorization code? from auth0 or azure AD?

2) Submitting authorization code for id_token and access_token

```
 a) are we submitting authorization code to auth0 or azure AD?

 b) do we get access_token, id_token from auth0 or azure AD?
```

Please bare me if I my question seems very basic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your app talks with Auth0.
Auth0 will give you the tokens.

In this setup, Auth0 is your app's identity provider. 
Auth0 then uses AAD as its identity provider. 
But from your app's perspective, the user authenticates with Auth0.

Comment: Thanks for quick, simple and straight forward answer. So if I implement SSO for my apps, then it should be done in Auth0, right? Please provide any sample code or links to do SSO for my apps using Auth0 and Azure AD.

Comment: Yeah, you'd integrate with Auth0. The fact that the user then uses Azure AD shouldn't really matter for your apps.